# Rails: filter records by business hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app which just keep records of license usage of a number of applications. The app would just poll license usage every X minutes.

I would like to filter the records so it will get records that are generated between business hours. The reason being to show the application usage during and off business hours.

Currently, i have the code to filter using mysql statement:-

```
app_usage.find(<app id>.feature.find(:all, 
 :conditions => ["name = ? and hour(created_at) > ? and 
  hour(created_at) < ? and dayofweek(created_at) not in (1,7)", 
 <feature_name>, 8, 18])
```

Of course, this won't work in sqlite3 database. I would like to know if there's a way to do it using ruby?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ActiveRecord has a method for these kinds of MySQL-specific functions. At least, I haven't found them. If you're looking for an equivalent of this query in sqlite, that would be something like this:

```
:conditions => ["name = ? and strftime('%H', created_at) > ? and strftime('%H', created_at) < ? and strftime('%w', created_at) not in (1,7)", <feature_name>, 8, 18]
```

This won't work for MySQL though.

Comment: thanks, i guess i have to do a for-loop filter after generating generic results.

Comment: That's always an option if the dataset isn't too big.